# Apache log with Munin question

Tags: apache-2.2, munin

In Munin Graph:

What is the meaning of 'apache accesses' and 'apache processes'? And what's the relation between them?

Answer (score 1):

**Processes:** The prefork MPM uses multiple child processes, each child handles one 
connection at a time.

**Accesses:** 
A total number of accesses